# Downloading files from amazon s3 using django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to the *Django framework*, I was trying to generate a link to download files from *Amazon S3*. I got this error when I tried to load the template page:

```
Reverse for 'myapp.views.handles3downloads' with arguments '(u'README.md',)'
and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^handles3downloads/(\d+)/$', handles3downloads),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def handles3downloads(request, fname):
    bucket_name = 'bucketname'
    key = s.get_bucket(bucket_name).get_key(fname)
    dfilename = key.get_contents_to_filename(fname)

    wrapper = HttpResponse(file(dfilename))
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/plain')
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(dfilename)
    return response
```

**template file**

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp.views.handles3downloads' sfile.linkUrl %}">{{sfile.linkUrl}}</a>
```

I looked at some of the solutions with similar errors but it didn't help me. Can anyone help me out please.

Advance thanks

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625047/django-newbie-reverse-not-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urls.py

```
url(r'^handles3downloads/', handles3downloads),
```

views.py

```
def handles3downloads(request):
  fname = request.GET['filename']
  bucket_name = 'bucketname'
  key = s.get_bucket(bucket_name).get_key(fname)
  key.get_contents_to_filename('/tmp/'+key.name)
  wrapper = FileWrapper(open('/tmp/'+fname, 'rb'))
  content_type = mimetypes.guess_type('/tmp/'+fname)[0]
  response = HttpResponse(wrapper,content_type=content_type)
  response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize('/tmp/'+fname)
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(fname)
```

templates

```
<a href="/handles3downloads/?filename=file1.jpg" rel="external">Download</a>
```

Comment: Would be nice if You tell us where came from variable "s". Also response needs to be returned, right.

Thank You.

Comment: The 's' variable is like the 's3_connection' variable in this example from boto 2:

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migrations3.html#accessing-a-bucket

`import boto
s3_connection = boto.connect_s3()`

`bucket = s3_connection.get_bucket('mybucket', validate=False)`

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression in the `urls.py` file seems to be wrong. Try using this instead:

```
url(r'^handles3downloads/(\w+)/$', handles3downloads),
```

You're passing parameter string to the view, and the `regex` is matching integers.

Comment: Hi, i am still getting the same error after changing the regex

Comment: Then probably you're not having a URL pattern with such name. [Consider naming your view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/), instead of using `myapp.views.handles3downloads'.

Answer (score 0):

Jordan is correct, there is a problem with your urls.py. You can tell by the error. You are trying to get a reverse on 'myapp.views.handles3downloads', but has that reverse string been identified? Try this.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^handles3downloads/([^/]+)/$', handles3downloads,
     name='myapp.views.handles3downloads'),
)
```